# 3d stuttering on 64bit Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card, 3d-graphics

I recently upgraded from 32bit Windows 7 to 64bit so I could use all the RAM in my laptop.

Everything works great except 3D, which stutters like crazy. This worked fine when I was on 32bit Windows 7.

I have the latest driver for the Quadro FX 770M that is in my Dell M4400. I got this via the NVidia utility on their site. I also tried the Dell driver from support.dell.com.

Both give the same results.

I have all the drivers installed for the motherboard, hard disk etc as given on the dell support page.

Does anyone else share this issue with 3D on 64bit Windows 7.

Comment: Get the latest driver from NVidia not from Dell.

Comment: I remember nvidia having terrible Windows Vista support until it had been out for about 6 months, especially since most Vista crashes were due to nvidia drivers. I hope they're not pulling the same stunt again in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest nVidia drivers (190/191) cause some stuttering with Windows 7 in certain games. Roll back your drivers to 186 and it should be fine. I'm waiting for a fix myself.

Answer (score 1):

In the nvidia control panel there should be a 3d settings tab. Make sure all these settings are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could try uninstalling the drivers and then run [Driver sweeper](http://blogote.com/2009/windows-ideas/download-nvidia-driver-cleaner-driver-sweeper-for-windows.html), then install the Nvidia drivers again.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with Aero disabled. I know that I get choppy streaming Netflix video if I don't disable Aero.

Comment: Good idea but it didn't fix it. Didn't chnage one bit... :(